# Dynamic style sheet Or condition based page layout in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am creating PDF document using xslt 1.0, where I have to apply some static content ("DAFT") on page based on data, like if COMPLETED = 0 then print "DRAFT"
on page otherwise not.

XML data which i used to generate PDF is like below, data will contains different customer and for every customer i am creating new page( using page break) in PDF, some time data will go to next page also..

I have tried to implement static content while i am creating new page/ applying page break, but problem is when data goes (overflow) to next page then this static content is not on next page, so I think this should be done by stylesheet some how which i don,t know.

XML DATA:

```
<ROWSET1>
  <ROWSET1_ROW>
  <ID_INVOICE>9404</ID_INVOICE>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>371</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <COM_LASTNAME>XYZ Lmt</COM_LASTNAME>
  <SALUTATION>Company</SALUTATION>
  <RG_CONTACTTYPE>OU</RG_CONTACTTYPE>
  <NAME1>XYZ Lmt</NAME1>
  <NAME2>COM EMP</NAME2>
  <COMPLETED>0</COMPLETED>
  <DATE_INVOICE>31.05.2017</DATE_INVOICE>
  <INVOICE_YEAR>2017</INVOICE_YEAR>
  <INVOICENR>487</INVOICENR>
  <APPLICATION_NR>7.384.883</APPLICATION_NR>
  <NAME_CUST>EMP1</NAME_CUST>
  <SENT_DATE>15.05.2017</SENT_DATE>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <INVOICENR_ORDER>4053</INVOICENR_ORDER>
  <SUM_PRODUCT>168</SUM_PRODUCT>
  <IS_INDEP_CONTACT>N</IS_INDEP_CONTACT>
 </ROWSET1_ROW>
 <ROWSET1_ROW>
  <ID_INVOICE>9404</ID_INVOICE>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>371</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <COM_LASTNAME>XYZ Lmt</COM_LASTNAME>
  <SALUTATION>Company</SALUTATION>
  <RG_CONTACTTYPE>OU</RG_CONTACTTYPE>
  <NAME1>XYZ Lmt</NAME1>
  <NAME2>COM EMP</NAME2>
  <COMPLETED>0</COMPLETED>
  <DATE_INVOICE>31.05.2017</DATE_INVOICE>
  <INVOICE_YEAR>2017</INVOICE_YEAR>
  <INVOICENR>487</INVOICENR>
  <APPLICATION_NR>7.384.883</APPLICATION_NR>
  <NAME_CUST>EMP2</NAME_CUST>
  <SENT_DATE>15.05.2017</SENT_DATE>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <INVOICENR_ORDER>4053</INVOICENR_ORDER>
  <SUM_PRODUCT>168</SUM_PRODUCT>
  <IS_INDEP_CONTACT>N</IS_INDEP_CONTACT>
 </ROWSET1_ROW>
 <ROWSET1_ROW>
 ...
</ROWSET1>
<ROWSET2>
 <ROWSET2_ROW>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>371</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <QUANTITY>290</QUANTITY>
  <APPLICATION_NR>1</APPLICATION_NR>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <PRICE>168</PRICE>
 </ROWSET2_ROW>
 <ROWSET2_ROW>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>371</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <QUANTITY>-12</QUANTITY>
  <APPLICATION_NR>4</APPLICATION_NR>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <PRICE>168</PRICE>
 </ROWSET2_ROW>
 <ROWSET2_ROW>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>859</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <QUANTITY>39</QUANTITY>
  <APPLICATION_NR>1</APPLICATION_NR>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <PRICE>169</PRICE>
 </ROWSET2_ROW>
 <ROWSET2_ROW>
  <ID_CUSTOMER>859</ID_CUSTOMER>
  <ID_PRODUCT>3</ID_PRODUCT>
  <QUANTITY>-2</QUANTITY>
  <APPLICATION_NR>4</APPLICATION_NR>
  <PRODUCTNAME>best product</PRODUCTNAME>
  <PRICE>169</PRICE>
 </ROWSET2_ROW>
 ...
</ROWSET2>
```

STYLE SHEET (stylesheet.xsl):

```
<xsl:template name="paperlayout">
        <xsl:param name="draft" select="false()"/>
        <xsl:param name="printheader"/>
        <fo:root>

            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="paperlayout">
                    <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="title" page-position="first"/>
                    <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" page-position="rest"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>

                <!-- title page-->
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="title" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="20mm" 
                margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="15mm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-bottom="30mm" margin-top="25mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-first" extent="0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="20.5mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <!-- rest page-->
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="20mm" 
                margin-bottom="0mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="15mm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-bottom="30mm" margin-top="25mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-rest" extent="0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="20.5mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>                
            </fo:layout-master-set>


            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="paperlayout">
                <!--############## header ##############-->
                <fo:static-content flow-name="header-first">
                    <xsl:if test="$draft">
                        <fo:block-container  position="absolute" left="0mm" top="05mm">
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                    <svg width="680" height="920" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                                       
                                        <text font-family="eurostyle" font-size="10pt" font-weight="900" style="fill:rgb(255,192,192)" x="260" y="20" width="680" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(-54, 340, 15)">
                                            DRAFT
                                        </text>
                                    </svg>
                                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$printheader">
                            <xsl:call-template name="logo"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <fo:block-container>
                                <fo:block><fo:leader /></fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>                       

                </fo:static-content>

                <fo:static-content flow-name="header-rest">
                    <xsl:if test="$draft">
                        <fo:block-container  position="absolute" left="0mm" top="05mm">
                            <fo:block>
                                <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                    <svg width="680" height="920" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">                                       
                                        <text font-family="eurostyle" font-size="10pt" font-weight="900" style="fill:rgb(255,192,192)" x="260" y="20" width="680" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(-54, 340, 15)">
                                            Entwurf
                                        </text>
                                    </svg>
                                </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:block-container>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$printheader">
                            <xsl:call-template name="logo"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <fo:block-container>
                                <fo:block><fo:leader /></fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>

                </fo:static-content>


                <!--############## footer ##############-->
                <xsl:if test="$printheader">
                    <xsl:call-template name="footerData"/>
                </xsl:if>

                <!--############## body ##############-->
                <fo:flow flow-name="body" xsl:use-attribute-sets="body">
                    <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
                    <fo:block id="endofdoc"></fo:block> 
                </fo:flow>

            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
```

XSLT CODE used to create PDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" 
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exslt math str">

    <xsl:import href="stylesheet.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="debug" select="false()"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dataRowset1" select="DOCUMENT/DATA/ROWSET1/ROWSET1_ROW"/>
    <xsl:param name="printheader" select="true()"/>

    <xsl:key name="key_cust_id" match="ROWSET1_ROW" use="ID_CUSTOMER"/>

    <!-- ###### Main template ###### -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="paperlayout">
            <xsl:with-param name="draft" select="//ROWSET1/ROWSET1_ROW/COMPLETED =  0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="printheader" select="$printheader"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="newline">
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>


    <!--############## body ##############-->
    <xsl:template name="body">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DOCUMENT/DATA" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA">

        <xsl:variable name="dataRowset2" select="ROWSET2" />
        <!-- Status M check -->
        <xsl:if test="ROWSET1 != ''">

            <fo:block-container xsl:use-attribute-sets="section">

                <xsl:variable name="dataRowset1" select="ROWSET1" />

                <xsl:for-each select="//ROWSET1_ROW[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('key_cust_id', ID_CUSTOMER)[1])]">
                    <xsl:sort select="COM_LASTNAME" />

                    <fo:block page-break-before="always"></fo:block>
                    <fo:table width="100%" font-family="calibri" font-size="10pt">
                        <xsl:call-template name="table-column-define" />
                        <fo:table-body>

                            <xsl:for-each select="key('key_cust_id', ID_CUSTOMER)">

                                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                                    <!-- print header of document like company name, date, invocie nr-->
                                    <xsl:call-template name="table-header" />
                                </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:call-template name="table-data"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>


                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                            <!-- START: when record end print TOTAL -->
                            <xsl:variable name="customer_id" select="ID_CUSTOMER"/>
                            <fo:table width="100%" font-family="calibri" font-size="10pt">
                                <xsl:call-template name="sub-table-column-define" />
                                <fo:table-body>

                                    <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="table-row">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="number-columns-spanned">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="5"/>
                                            </xsl:attribute>
                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$newline"/></fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>                    
                                    </fo:table-row> 

                                    <xsl:for-each
                                        select="$dataRowset2/ROWSET2_ROW[ID_CUSTOMER/text() = $customer_id]">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="sub-table-data" />
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                            <!-- END: when record end print TOTAL -->   
                </xsl:for-each>

            </fo:block-container>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In above code I am creating key on id_customer, whenever new customer found I am creating header of page then print data belong to this customer in table which come in ROWSET1 then at then end i am printing total which come in ROWSET2.

At then begging of this code, I am passing parameter in style sheet which print "DRAFT" on whole PDF or NOT PRINT AT all, but i want to print draft on every page for particular company which have "COMPLETED = 0" and not printing DRAFT for those company which is not satisfy this condition.

Comment: This has nothing in particular to do with Java, and it seems only incidentally to involve XSLT.  The question seems primarily about XSL-FO.  Tags edited.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `<fo:marker>` and `<fo:retrieve-marker>`. That should do the job. Markers will never be displayed, regardless of if they have content or not. Thats because the retrieve marker searches for a marker on your specified position and displays its content in itself. So if you put nothing into your marker, the retrieve marker will display nothing. If there is content, the retrieve marker will display the content. 
The marker has to be in a flow. The retrieve marker has to be in a static-content. That way the retrieve marker will search for the last content of a marker and you can have different static-contents. 
Hope that helps you a bit.

Heres the link to some documentation: [markers example](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/anwendungsbeispiele/beispiel-9/)